# Differences between empty project and win32 console project in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When I use GCC with no IDE, I just need to create *.h file and *.cpp files.

But in VS2005, there are two ways to create an empty project, first way is to use "general -> Empty Project", second way is "Win32 -> Win32 console project ->next ->empty project".

The official [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms235629.aspx) recommends the second way while I preffer the first way.

Then what's the differeces between them?

In win32 console project, "subsystem" is "console", "Character Set" is "unicode". But in empty project, "subsystem" is "NoSet", "Character Set" is  "multi bytes". What does this mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An "Empty project" is just that: Empty. It has no specific settings at all, you need to set things like that yourself. For an empty "Console project" the IDE sets up the project with nice flags and settings for a console project, but doesn't add any files.

If you want a console program, then you most certainly should use the console project type.

Comment: Thanks. Is it means when i use "general ->empty project", then add test.h and test.cpp files in it, then build just like the way of gcc, it will go wrong? I will give it a test.

Comment: When i use the operations above, it works well, so i am still confused. But i'll accept your suggestions because "win32 console project" is the general way.

Comment: @jiahilegass It depends a lot on what you are doing I guess. If it works for you then great, but just be cautioned that some of the flags and settings setup by the console project template might be needed to do any work with the Windows API (which is used for much more than the actual GUI).

Comment: I know. My purpose is just to create an program like "hello world" in a standard way which just needs some api like "std::cout" in iostream. I would not use some win32 api in windows.h.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the @JoachimPileborg answer, what matters is project subsystem specification. For VS2005, there is a list of targeted subsystems: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk(v=vs.80).aspx

For empty project, it won't be set.

For Console, it would set to CONSOLE

I would recommend setting it to win32 console project, but remove precompiled headers flag and make it empty

Comment: Thanks for help. I prefer to it because the precompiled headers always make a green hand like me confused. But i will also try to learn some knowledge about it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

The #include  in the console project is not ANSI standard and will not work on other compilers.